# Why does javascript not not fire on page change in Gatsby project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a trustpilot widget that renders fine on initial load. Then when i change pages, the trustpilot widget resorts back to default logo with no data showing.

I tried removing the external trustpilot js within componentDidMount, then adding it back in, to try refresh but didnt work.

I thought I could manually add in the trustpilot html again. Is there a way to do this in gatsby? and will this work? the below didnt work.

```
$('#trustpilot').after('<div class="trustpilot-widget trustpilot-carousel" data-locale="...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding jQuery selectors (pointing directly to the DOM) in a React-based project, mixing different stuff and logic. While with React, you are creating and manipulating a virtual DOM (vDOM), which is hydrated on-demand by React.

When you change the page, the `<div>` that you are requesting may not be rendered yet or your code changes are not being persisted (mount/unmount and rehydration issues).

> I thought I could manually add in the trustpilot html again. Is there
> a way to do this in gatsby?

Something that may work for you is to use the `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` APIs, specifically the [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement)/[`wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement). Both of them will wrap your code (used in both files) and will avoid the unmounting components through the pages, persisting your Truspilot widget.

```
const React = require("react")
const Layout = require("./src/components/layout").default

exports.wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
}
```

Regarding what you've commented so far, [customizing the `html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) may fit your requirements to add the script, but this won't save you to unmount the component on each route change.